# EntityEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject() is the same as EntityEntry.Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I simply try to update an entity with method **ProjeleriGuncelle** below.

When I try to access the original values of the object in an overridden **SaveChangesAsync** with **EntityEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject()**, I see that the object contains the current values instead of the old ones.

Am I missing something? I expect **clonedTypedEntity** to have the values before update.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> ProjeleriGuncelle(Proje proje)
{
    var projeFound = DataContext.Projeler.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.EntegrasyonId == proje.EntegrasyonId);
    var entry = DataContext.Entry<Proje>(projeFound);

    //Database entry is updated with the proje object as expected
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(proje);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var modifiedEntries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
    foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        //modifiedEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject() returns the object with the currrent values instead of the original values before update
        if (modifiedEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject() is not IVersionable clonedTypedEntity) continue;
        clonedTypedEntity.Id = 0;
        clonedTypedEntity.UstSurumId = (modifiedEntry.Entity as IVersionable)?.Id;

        Add(clonedTypedEntity);
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

**Update :**

When I remove **AsNoTracking()** when querying for **projeFound**, `modifiedEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject()` really returns values before update. But I don't understand the behaviour, because with `var entry = DataContext.Entry<Proje>(projeFound);` statement, I expect that `entry` object is tracked, and by updating it with `entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(proje);` I expect to have access to original values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF the original values are the values when it starts tracking, which is when `entry.State = EntityState.Modified;` is called. EF is oblivious of the changes that happened in the previous line of code.

You could solve it by swapping both lines:

```cs
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified; // attaches and stores original values
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(proje);
```

An improvement would be to attach the entry and let the change tracker figure out if the entity was really modified.

```cs
    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; // attaches and stores original values
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(proje);
```

Now `SetValues` only marks actually changed properties as modified and the update statement can be much slimmer, or even not happen at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in this days....
In my Dbcontext i set this property:

```cs
ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

this property disable all tracking and you can not have their OriginalValue.

Comment: We had to use **EntityEntry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject()** instead, and that causes extra call to database, which we don't prefer for sure.